# Deadline, date limite, échéance, date butoir

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, synonymes

Peut-on employer le mot deadline en français ? Le cas échéant comment faut-il le prononcer ?

Échéance et date butoir sont-ils courants et peuvent-ils remplacer date limite ?

Comment: Tu parles de la deadline pour la soumission d'un papier ou pour autre chose ?

Comment: Deadline de la soumission d'un papier, d'un mémoire, d'un "assignment", etc.

Comment: Dans le milieu scientifique universitaire c'est parfaitement connu pour des raisons tout à fait évidentes. C'est le terme attendu, que tout le monde emploie. Cela dit, je ferais en soute d'éviter de l'écrire. Échéance ne convient pas dans ce cas. Date butoir conviendrait, mais ça risque de surprendre un peu.

Comment: @Saint-Jacques: Probablement dans tous les domaines, il y a une large majorité de conférences internationales. On peut deviner dans quelle langue sont écrits les formulaires de soumission et d'inscription…

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je sais et ce n'est même pas récent, je me souviens que c'est la seule langue dans laquelle venait le manuel d'instruction de mon premier ordi etc. Peut-être que la France va toujours être à l'abri fondamentalement, vu le nombre ou l'indivisibilité. Merci !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le mot *deadline*, toujours prononcé à l'anglaise, est de plus en plus courant en France, spécialement à l'oral et dans un contexte professionnel, pour désigner la date et ou l'heure avant laquelle il faut remettre un document, fournir une réponse, s'inscrire à quelque chose, payer une facture, livrer un matériel, etc.

Contrairement à l'usage québécois, il est utilisé au féminin en France :

> — C'est quand **la** deadline pour l'appel d'offres ?
>
> — C'est demain, faut qu'on se bouge !

A l'écrit, *date limite* est le plus courant :

> Date limite de dépôt des soumissions à l'appel d'offre.

Answer (score 2):

Le mot « deadline » semble ne pas être employé en français, cependant un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deadline&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeadline%3B%2Cc0) donne une information surprenante et on le trouve dans le [reverso](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/deadline/forced); la prononciation est la même qu'en anglais; on trouve en rapport avec l'expression « meet a(the) deadline(s) » et le terme « deadline » les traductions « [date butoir](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/meet+a+deadline.html) », « délai », « date limite », « date fixée » et « échéance ».

« Échéance » et « délai » sont des [termes courants](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A9ch%C3%A9ance%2Cdate+butoir%2Cdate+limite%2Cdate+fix%C3%A9e%2Cd%C3%A9lai&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A9ch%C3%A9ance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdate%20butoir%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdate%20limite%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdate%20fix%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cd%C3%A9lai%3B%2Cc0) mais pas les autres.

Comment: Je crois que le délai concerne la période jusqu'à le "deadline" et pas la date limite.

Comment: Ngram montre que l'emploi de mot deadline s'augmente. Alors si on l'utilise,  on prononce à là françaiset ?

Comment: @dimitris Oui, c'est exact, mais dans les traductions au lieu de dire « respecter la date limite » qui correspond à un délai on peut aussi dire « respecter le délai » et vice versa.

Comment: @dimitris Non, écoutez la prononciation dans le reverso : c'est approximativement la prononciation anglaise.

Comment: Je te remercie vivement. D'après toi, son emploi va choquer un auditoire du supérieur  (licence scientifique) ?

Comment: Après nos nombreuses échanges je crois pouvoir tutoyer. Si ça te dérange je peux continuer à vouvoyer.

Comment: @dimitris Je ne peux pas dire si oui ou non il passerait sans irriter quelque peu; apparemment le mot est bien implanté et les gens ne le connaissant pas auront vite fait de s'informer. Il ne devrait cependant pas choquer, on entend de nouveaux mots anglais dans le langage en permanence. Je viens d'apprendre celui-ci.

Comment: Parfait. Merci encore une fois.

Comment: @dimitris Faites comme il vous plait, tu ou vous.

Comment: En effet vivio  (apk android) donne un exemple d'emploi de deadline en français qui date de 1993 (Jaques Derrida, Passions).

Comment: @dimitris j'ai déjà entendu plusieurs fois ce mot, prononcé à l'anglaise, tant en contexte professionnel que scolaire ;) (en France du moins)

Answer (score 2):

Je suis davantage habitué à ceci dans le contexte précisé en [commentaires](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32639/deadline-date-limite-%C3%A9ch%C3%A9ance-date-butoir#comment66960_32639) :

> Date limite pour/de la remise du/des travail/travaux.
>  À remettre
>   (avant) le [date], (avant) [heure].
>  — Quand doit-on remettre le
>   travail ? — (Au plus tard) Le 15 décembre avant 21:00.

On emploie parfois *deadline* ; je le prononce exactement comme en anglais (avec mon accent). On a plusieurs autres options possibles selon les contextes et la formulation :

> *échéance, date d’échéance, limite, dernière limite, date limite, heure limite, date butoir, heure* ou *date de tombée* (dans le monde
>   des médias), *date d’expiration, délai, dernier délai, délai de
>   rigueur, date de clôture, clôture des inscriptions, terme, délai
>   butoir, heure* ou *jour de bouclage* (dans le monde de la presse).
>
> [ *Banque de dépannage linguistique* (OQLF), [*deadline*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=deadline&btn_chercher=CHERCHER&id=3668). ]

À mon avis, l'adverbe interrogatif (*quand*) avec le verbe et la *date limite* me semblent un peu plus usuels et courants que la *date d'échéance* et bien davantage que la *date butoir*.

Comment: Je crois que la notion de **date butoir** est utilisée pour expliciter que les conséquences de ne pas respecter les échéanciers seront particulièrement dramatiques: on se passera de vos services, ou des quantités importantes d'argent seront perdues en vain, ou les candidatures ne seront plus retenues, ou un otage sera tué, etc. L'image du butoir qui résistera statiquement à tous les assauts.